# Making an application like Settings default application - do I need a myriad of view controllers?

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm making a settings menu in my application, and so far I'm making separate view controller for every screen. Is this a correct way of doing that? It grows very fast, and I am not sure it is an optimal way. For example, I have:

1. `UINavigationViewController` that is main controller of settings tab.
2. Under it I have `UITableViewController` that shows main settings screen.
3. When I click any settings cell in the middle, it sends me to its own view controller.
4. And I need different models to keep every part of every view controller settings separate, or can I just fill them up into one file?

And as I have many customizable settings, do I really need separate view controller for every settings button? This looks overly complicated.

Comment: This is exactly what storyboards are good for. Just draw out the controls you need and connect them up to your source files, then segue between view controllers. IB should do quite a bit of the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend to some extent on the specific types of settings that you need. For simple on/off settings you can use a `UISwitch` control directly in your main `TableView` (see Airplane Mode in the main Settings app as an example).

For any other types of settings that are similar you can use a single generic view controller that is passed the necessary parameters for each setting. For example, maybe you have five different settings that all involve picking one item from a list. These could all call the same controller, passing an array of choices and a reference to the parameter rather than recreating essentially the same view five times.

By doing this and also grouping related settings into a single view (again, see the main Settings app for examples), you should be able to keep the number of necessary controllers to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You have options, you can create multiple views and apply a navigation-like push animation varying the view. However, a better way, and where they **finally** come into use, is using a storyboard.

A storyboard is **one** file that can hold many view controllers and you can link interactions, it's really hard to use from my experience, but is exactly what you are looking for.